# jQuery function doesn't run as expected inside CDN script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code. I'm over Arch Linux, if this is a important thing...I'm tired of trying different libraries, in local, from jquery's site but it does't work...

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#header").hide();
                    $("#header").fadeIn(2000);
                });
            </script>
            <title>1</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 id="header" align="center">Page content</h1>
            <p align="center">
                Footer
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Put your jQuery call and your custom script in separate tags.

Comment: Yes..whas that, what a silly. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Put your jQuery call and your custom script in separate tags.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#header").hide();
        $("#header").fadeIn(2000);
    });
</script>
```

Note that with HTML5 you don't need to specify type for JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong way of using `script` tag !

Make sure you properly wrapped your jQuery code inside a `<script></script>` block. Also close all open `script` blocks.

This should work

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#header").hide();
               $("#header").fadeIn(2000);
            });
        </script>
        <title>1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="header" align="center">Page content</h1>
        <p align="center">
            Footer
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Working [sample](http://jsbin.com/yogopaheya/edit?html,output)